# Cryptography Basics

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

I am an individual who is really interested in cryptography and cryptanalysis. But I am a mere beginner. I am teaching myself mathematical cryptology and python. What more can I do to call myself a(n amateur) cryptographer? Am I in the right track?

Comment: Please don't take this as me being rude, that is not my intention. The most important thing you can learn is how to learn. You shouldn't have to come here to ask the kind of question you have asked. You should be able to find answers to that on your own. Then, the next thing you should do is, as you learn and have specific questions, come back here to seek answers. Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Questioner gone, probably never to return. Jaw dropping.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to read the "[crypto textbook](http://www.crypto-textbook.com/)" by Dr. Christof Paar, who teaches crypto at the university of Bochum in Germany (don't worry, of course it's written in english).

His lectures which are also available on youtube (also in english ;) , [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aHkqB2-46k) is the first of twenty-four parts) basicly go hand in hand with the book.

The first chapter is also available as PDF for free on the website and you can check it out before buying it.

If you want to start trying some hands-on stuff, visit [hacking-lab](https://www.hacking-lab.com/index.html). You will find some CTF-Challenges there to try out.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read Goldwasser and Bellare's ["Lecture Notes on Cryptography"](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/gb.html) to learn more about the theory of cryptography.